# Let $ W_1 $ and $ W_2 $ be subspaces of $ V^* $. Prove that $ W_1 = W_2 $ iff $ Ann(W_1) = Ann(W_2) $

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $ S $ be any subset of $ V^* $ for some finite dimensional space $ V $. Define $ Ann(S) = \lbrace v \in V ~|~ f(v) = 0 $ for all $ f \in S \rbrace $.

Let $ W_1 $ and $ W_2 $ be subspaces of $ V^* $. Prove that $ W_1 = W_2 $ iff $ Ann(W_1) = Ann(W_2) $.

I read a solution:

Suppose that $ Ann(W_1) = Ann(W_2) $. Let $ \lbrace v^*_{i_1}, \ldots, v^*_{i_k} \rbrace  $ denote a basis for $ W_1 $ with $ 1 \leq i_1  \leq \cdots \leq i_k \leq n$. For every $ f \in W_1 , f(v) = 0 $.

So the subspace $ Ann(W_1) $ has the basis $ \lbrace v_{j_1}, \ldots, v_{j_l} \rbrace $, where every index in $ \lbrace j_1, \ldots, j_l \rbrace  $ distinct from any of $ \lbrace i_1, \ldots, i_k \rbrace $. Moreover $ Ann(W_2) $ also has the basis $ \lbrace v_{j_1}, \ldots, v_{j_l} \rbrace $. **Therefore a basis for $ W_2 $ contains $ \lbrace v^*_{i_1}, \ldots, v^*_{i_k} \rbrace  $** and $ f \in W_2 $. Similarly if $ f \in W_2 $ then $ f \in W_1 $, as well. Hence $ W_1 = W_2 $ as desired.

I wonder if the bold line  is correct. If not, give me hints to proof this execise, please.

Comment: There seems to be something unusual about what you wrote. You said "$Ann(W_1)$ has the basis $\{v_{j_1}, \ldots, v_{j_l}\}$" twice.

Comment: ok.I edited. thanks!

Comment: You seem to use implicitly the basis $\{v_1\dots v_n\}$ of $V$ together with the dual basis $\{v_1^*\dots v_n^*\}$ of $V^*$, with $v_i^*(v_j)=\delta_{ij}$.